# How to deal with functions returning objects with generic type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, static-typing

Here's simplified example of something I'm trying to accomplish. I have a function that produces HashMap of different signature depending on type of Field object that is passed to it. I'm not sure what's the best way to deal with this. Any help appreciated.

```
trait Field
case class IntField extends Field {
    def convert(x: String): Int = x.toInt
}
case class StringField extends Field {
    def convert(x: String): String = x
}
case class DoubleField etc...

def someFunc(field: Field): HashMap[?, Int] = {
    val index = new HashMap[?, Int]() // This needs to be [String, Int] or [Int, Int] or [Double, Int]

    val data = // some data from csv file that will be parsed

    for (line <- data) {
        val values = field.convert(data) // can return String or Int or Double
        index.put(values, 0)       
    }
    index
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by adding a type parameter to your Field trait (I added the HashMap import and set data explicitly to "123" to be able to test this in the REPL):

```
trait Field[A] {
    def convert(x: String): A // Need to define convert for the trait, too.
}
case class IntField extends Field[Int] {
    def convert(x: String): Int = x.toInt
}
case class StringField extends Field[String] {
    def convert(x: String): String = x
}
//case class DoubleField etc...

import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
def someFunc[A](field: Field[A]): HashMap[A, Int] = {
    val index = new HashMap[A, Int]() // This needs to be [String, Int] or [Int, Int] or [Double, Int]

    val data = "123"// some data from csv file that will be parsed

    for (line <- data) {
        val values = field.convert(data) // can return String or Int or Double
        index.put(values, 0)
    }
    index
}
```

Now a call to someFunc will determine the type from the passed-in Field and generate an appropriately-typed HashMap out:

```
scala> someFunc(IntField())
res1: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(123 -> 0)

scala> :t res1
scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int]

scala> someFunc(StringField())
res2: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map(123 -> 0)

scala> :t res2
scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int]
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense but there is a little problem. someFunc is called in a loop over sequence with Field type items which is causing type mismatch error - `for (field <- fields) someFunc(field)`

Comment: @marcin_koss You'll need to provide more info on your secondary problem if you want proper help with that - maybe a new question? If it is because you are now getting a sequence of HashMaps, each with different types, then you are probably running into problems because HashMap is invariant in its types, so you can't just build up a `Seq[HashMap[Any, Int]]` - you might need to rethink what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Returning HashMap from someFunc() is not a requirement for what I need, it's ok if someFunc returned Unit. It seems like at this point the only problem I have is how to execute someFunc() recursively heaving different Field itms in a List. Since list is now a mix of different types compiler doesn't know with what type someFunc() will be called and I'm not sure if there are ways to give that information in the current design.